# How to switch the global font family and update $font-family-base in bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, fonts

I have following font-family set on form body:
[The font which I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8neTV.png)

Now I need following font-family:
[The font family I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9IVp.png)

This link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/reboot/ tells following :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjPWJ.png)

So according to this link the default dropped and replaced with a “native font stack”.
To switch the global font-family, I need to update $font-family-base and recompile Bootstrap. I am new to bootstrap. Please let me know how to change font-family for my entire form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
html,* {
font-family: '--apple-system','san-serif',
font-size:16px;
}
```

Comment: you can put these into your .css file to execute